# Javascript splice and push in for loop adds items multiple times

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice, conways-game-of-life

I am attempting to learn Javascript by implementing Conway's Game of Life but unfortunately, I am stuck right at the beginning.

I have a matrix:

```
[
  [0,0,0,0], 
  [0,0,0,0], 
  [0,0,0,0], 
  [0,0,0,0]
]
```

and would like to simulate a border of "1"s which surround the matrix. 
My final matrix should be:

```
[
  [1,1,1,1,1,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,1], 
  [1,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,1], 
  [1,0,0,0,0,1], 
  [1,1,1,1,1,1]
]
```

So far, I have written the following code:

```js
var matrix = [[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]];

function addBorder(m) {

  var row = []
  for (var i=0; i<m[0].length; i++) {
    row.push(0);
  }

  m.splice(0, 0, row);
  m.push(row);

  for (var i=0; i<m.length; i++) {
    m[i].splice(0,0,1);
    m[i].push(1);
  }

  return m;
}

addBorder(matrix).forEach(i => console.log(i.join(',')))
```

The output matrix is almost what I want, but not quite. However, if I change the second for loop to  `(var i=0; i<m.length; i++)`, the code produces the right matrix. Unfortunately, I have no idea why it does not work initially but with this altered line of code. Why does it add two items at the first and last loop? I am grateful for any hint!

Comment: The main problem is that you add *the same* array (`row`) twice to the initial matrix. So if you manipulate it in any way, you'd get both the first and the last item to change, since they refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the additional 1s in the first and last row is that they are the same row-object. You should avoid putting the same row object twice in your matrix.

So change:

```
m.splice(0, 0, row);
m.push(row);
```

to:

```
m.splice(0, 0, row);
m.push([...row]); // create a copy of row, and push that.
```

Now when you perform your loop to pre- and postfix a 1, you'll be sure to target a different row object each time.

Unrelated, but `m.unshift(row)` would be the same as `m.splice(0, 0, row)`.

In a more functional way, without mutating the original array, you could write the function like this:

```js
function addBorder(m) {
     return [
         Array(m.length+2).fill(1),
         ...m.map(row => [1, ...row, 1]),
         Array(m.length+2).fill(1)
     ];
}

var matrix = [[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]];

console.log(addBorder(matrix));
```

Of course, you can still decide to assign the result to the original matrix variable:

```
matrix = addBorder(matrix)
```